# Need help in parallel testing from pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have 100 Java class file for testing.

I want to divide them with 4 xml files.
(100 classes divided into below xml files)

```
testng1.xml
testng2.xml
testng3.xml
testng4.xml
```

testng.xml file

```
<suite name="MainSuite" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
    </listeners>
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="testng1.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testng2.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testng3.xml" />
        <suite-file path="testng4.xml" />
    </suite-files>
 </suite>
```

pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                <value>4</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When executing (mvn clean test) it is starting execution but i can't find where it is failed.

I want to generate proper report for failed and passed classes with different suit.

I have tried **ReportNG** but it is not generating report from testng because i'm running project from **POM.xml** (mvn clean test)

Comment: pom.xml doesn't allow you to run test parallel. It can be achieved through testng.xml file or something like Jenkins.

Comment: It is executing parallel all testng file parallel with above code

Comment: Then what is you actual question ?

Comment: I want to generate proper report for failed and passed classes with different suit.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one testNG.xml file in your project 
So you can define all your all test classes within the xml and then can run parallely by just mentioning **parallel="classes"**

```
<suite name="Test-class Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2" >   
    <test name="Test-class test" >
    <classes>
      <class name="ParallelClassesTestOne" />
      <class name="ParallelClassesTestTwo" />
    </classes>   </test>
```

then you can see our test results in testoutput folder >emailable Report

Comment: I don't prefer that according to my project.
There might be thousands of testcases, so Multiple testng file is necessary.

Comment: It does not execute in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of dividing then in 4 xml file. you can maintain them in single file. create 4 `<test>` in that xml file and categorise your test for parallel execution.

e.g.

```
<suite name="All_in_one_suite" parallel="test" thread-count="2" >   
    <test name="Test group 1" >
     <classes>
       <class name="ParallelClassesTestOne" />
       <class name="ParallelClassesTestTwo" />
     </classes>   
    </test>

    <test name="Test group 2" >
     <classes>
       <class name="ParallelClassesTestOne" />
       <class name="ParallelClassesTestTwo" />
     </classes>   
    </test>
    .....
<suite>
```

And better approach people follow is provide groups name in your testcase and use that group name instead of writing 100 class name

```
    <test name="stack 1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="regression" />
            </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.test.name.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
```